# VBA Excel: Array of cells including merged cell values

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

Let's say we have the following array:

[image: Excel array]

The second and third cells are merged together.
How do I make an array to read the third value as 2 instead of empty?

Current code:
`Sub arrayTest()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 1))
    Debug.Print rng(1) & "," & rng(2) & "," & rng(3) & "," & rng(4)
End Sub`
Output: `1,2,,4`

Comment: `Range(3,1).MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value` works to get the value, but I want the array to pick it up automatically

Comment: So you want the second value to be blank, or three values to be returned? How are you using this output?

Comment: I want to make an array with values from a column, without specifying for each cell if it is merged or not. The debug.Print is just to indicate if it is done successfully (debugging purposes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue myself. This works for how I wanted it to work:
`Sub arrayTest2()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    With Worksheets(1)
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    Dim cellA As Range
    Dim arrayA() As Variant
    ReDim arrayA(LastRow)

    For Each cellA In rng
        arrayA(cellA.Row) = cellA.MergeArea(Cells(1, 1).Value)
        Debug.Print arrayA(cellA.Row)
    Next cellA
End Sub`

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the empty cells from printing using a loop

```
Dim i As Integer

Sub arrayTest()
Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 2))
    For i = 0 To 4
        If Not IsEmpty(rng(i)) Then
           Debug.Print rng(i)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In place, I don't think it will be possible to make Excel read as the way you want (unless you build an array in memory using loop like Matt has demonstrated). If I have understood correctly then you want output like 1,2,2,4.

Example code to get such result using a temporary empty column:

```
    Sub ArrayTest2()
    Const tmpCol As Long = 2 '\\ Change this to suit. This will be your temporary column
    Dim rngIn As Range, rngOut As Range
    Set rngIn = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(4, 1))
    rngIn.Copy Cells(1, tmpCol)
    Set rngOut = Cells(1, tmpCol).Resize(rngIn.Count, 1)
    With rngOut
        .UnMerge
        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count > 0 Then .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Debug.Print rngOut(1) & "," & rngOut(2) & "," & rngOut(3) & "," & rngOut(4)
    Cells(1, tmpCol).EntireColumn.Delete
    End Sub
```